# Modula-2: how to assign a procedure to a pointer?

Tags: syntax, function-pointers, modula-2

I am stuck with the assignment of a procedure to a pointer in Modula-2.

```
PROCEDURE print(node : Node_ptr);
BEGIN
(* some code *)
END print;

TYPE Node_ptr   = POINTER TO Node;
TYPE Visit_ptr  = POINTER TO PROCEDURE (Node_ptr);

TYPE
    Node = RECORD
        parent  : Node_ptr;
        left    : Node_ptr;
        right   : Node_ptr;
        id      : INTEGER;
        visit   : Visit_ptr;
END;
```

This somehow compiles.

But I do not know how to assign the print procedure to the visit member of my Node record. I need something like this:

```
node^.visit^ := print;
```

(Even the POINTER TO PROCEDURE definition took me a while to figure out...)

Comment: Try to assign the address of the procedure to the pointer: `node^.visit = ADR(print)`

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment syntax is correct (after you declare node as Node_ptr and allocate space to it).

For more information, I would recommend reading Wirth, "Programming in Modula-2".  You can find good used copies USD.  It is terse but contains probably all you need.  (Other tutorials may be found on http://freepages.modula2.org/tutor.html .)